# Xamarin stack-layout sometimes overlap

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I implemented a menu through stack-layout in Xamarin.

But sometimes my menu would overlap. Sometimes not.

It only happened on Android.

Here is the code.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ContentPage
    xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
    xmlns:sfPopup="clr-namespace:Syncfusion.XForms.PopupLayout;assembly=Syncfusion.SfPopupLayout.XForms"
    x:Class="XXX">
    <ContentPage.Content>
        <ScrollView Orientation="Vertical">
            <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical" Padding="0" Spacing="0">
            
                <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical" Padding="0" Spacing="0">
                    <StackLayout x:Name="Block_1" Orientation="Vertical" Padding="10,0,0,0" Spacing="0">
                        <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" Padding="0,5,0,5" Spacing="10">
                            //Some content label/image...
                        </StackLayout>

                        <StackLayout x:Name="Item_1" Padding="0,0,0,10" Spacing="5">
                            //Some content label/image...
                        </StackLayout>

                        <StackLayout x:Name="Item_2" Padding="0,0,0,10" Spacing="5">
                            //Some content label/image...
                        </StackLayout>
                    </StackLayout>

                    <BoxView Color="#1E5084" WidthRequest="1000" HeightRequest="1"/>

                    <StackLayout x:Name="Block_2" Orientation="Vertical" Padding="10,0,0,0" Spacing="0">
                        <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" Padding="0,5,0,5" Spacing="10">
                            //Some content label/image...
                        </StackLayout>

                        <StackLayout x:Name="Item_3" Padding="0,0,0,10" Spacing="5">
                            //Some content label/image...
                        </StackLayout>

                        <StackLayout x:Name="Item_4" Padding="0,0,0,10" Spacing="5">
                            //Some content label/image...
                        </StackLayout>
                    </StackLayout>

                </StackLayout>
            </StackLayout>
        </ScrollView>
    </ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>
```

When the Item_1 and Item_2 in Block_1 is set to visible=false,

The content of Block_2 should be on top of the screen.

But when I set Item_1 and Item_2 to visibie=true

The Blcok_2 should just being pushed to lower part.

But sometimes the content of Item_1 and Item_2 just overlapped on Block_2.

Sometimes it works as expected(Being pushed lower)

What would be the problem?

Comment: I could not reproduce the issue,maybe you could share a samle which could reproduce it.

Comment: Awfully nested layout that could have been done using a Grid instead. Try to reduce your nesting and amount of layout passes that your code needs for this.

Comment: @LeoZhu-MSFT This issue only happened on other region's customer... Not able to repeat at my side too.

Comment: @Cheesebaron I implement the menu expand and collapse through set the visible of the stack-layout. If I implement this page through grid view. Could you suggest the way to expand or collapse through a grid view. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Ok you have 3 Stacklayout containers with content above, then a BoxView as a line and then 3 Stacklayout containers with content below the line, but when exactly does something overlap an when not? Whats the Content that you use in the Stacklayouts ? In addition, each Stacklayout has an Orientation, you don't need the vertical orientation here if the elements are to be arranged one below the other. You better do that with VerticalOptions StartAndExpand, then the individual elements automatically adapt to the predecessor.

Comment: This issue only happened on customer's device...for sometimes. Not able to repeat on my device.. I do not know the exactly repeat procedure. Thank you for response.

Comment: Thanks for the hint, I won't post any more answers as long as I don't have enough reputation. Ok, I'll ask again here, but I think if he don't uses Orientation = Vertical, but VerticalOptions = StartAndExpand , the problem should be resolved.